# Use an External Prediction as One of the Inputs in a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, prediction

Is it possible to use a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) such as LSTM to make a prediction with some historical data and a prediction from another source as inputs?

Example:

| t(..) | t(-2) | t(-1) | t(n) | t(+1) | t(+2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x(..) | x(-2) | x(-1) | x(n) | ????? | ????? |
| y(..) | y(-2) | y(-1) | y(n) | ????? | ????? |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | x'(1) | x'(2) |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | y'(1) | y'(2) |

(...)

| t(..) | t(-1) | t(0) | t(n+1) | t(+2) | t(+3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x(..) | x(-1) | x(0) | x(n+1) | ????? | ????? |
| y(..) | y(-1) | y(0) | y(n+1) | ????? | ????? |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | x'(2) | x'(3) |
| ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | y'(2) | y'(3) |

So I want to predict x and y in t(+1) and t(+2) with some historical data from them. But I also have a prediction that might give me some clues about x and y, called x' and y', that were genereated previously. For each time step there is some historical data and a forecast (x' and y'). Can I incorporate these predictions (x' and y') into my model in training?

I just want to know if a RNN could use another prediction as an input. Thank you.